# First jQuery project - Using a variable as a selector

Tags: jquery, variables

What I'm trying to do is quite simple but as a beginner I'm getting incredibly frustrated with it.

Here's my [first attempt just to give you the idea](http://andylamb.net/temp/9872_gangsters_moll_1st_attempt.html) .

I plan to do something a bit more fancy with the images, but I could see straight away that this wasn't the solution. Mouseover was changing the image before it had faded out and looked horrible.

So, I thought I might put all the images in the same place and hide them, making them visible and bringing them to the front on mouseover of the corresponding hotspot. I'm hoping there's a way to decrement an element's z-index value with .css().

Here's where I am with it (same URL, 9872_gangsters_moll_2nd_attempt.html).

```
$(".hotspot").mouseover(function(){
          //Get the id of this triggered item
          var imageid = $(this).attr("id");
          //use it to make corresponding image id to use as jQuery selector
          var currentImg = '#img_'+ imageid;
  //      alert(currentImg);                   //shows variable is correct
  //      $('.product-img').show();            //works fine with a class
          $('currentImg').show();                //doesn't work with a variable
          $('currentImg').addClass('front');     //same, obviously
});
```

I tried toggling visibility with css originally, but went with jQuery's show/hide. Neither worked. The problem seems to be with passing 'currentImg' as a selector.

Any help you could offer with this would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the quotes making it use a literal string (instead of your variable). `$('currentImg')` should be just `$(currentImg)`, like this:

```js
$(".hotspot").mouseover(function(){
   var currentImg = '#img_'+this.id;
   $(currentImg).show().addClass('front')
});
```

The other change above... things like [`.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) are DOM properties, you can access them directly (as opposed to the less efficient `.attr("id")`).

Comment: @andylamb: Re Nick's final comment, about `id`: Specifically, notice he used `this.id` (the `id` property on the *raw* DOM object), rather than `$(this).attr("id")` (wrapping a jQuery instance around the DOM object [`$(this)`] and then calling a function [`attr`] to look up the ID). You can safely do this with `id`, `src` on images, `href` on links, and a few others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and especially for the extra info re: raw DOM objects. Hugely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`$('currentImg').show();` is using a *string literal*, not a variable. Get rid of the quote marks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Needed a fresh pair of eyes

Answer (score 0):

When you enclose a set of alphabets within single quotes or double quotes, it becomes a string literal. 
When you say $('currentImg'), it will search for an html tag with name 'currentImg'. What you need is $(currentImg) as mentioned by @Nick and @David

Comment: Thanks Srisa. I was just testing *ahem* ;)